# play html video on bootstrap 3.3.4 active carousel and stop on next or previous

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

i want to play html5 video on active slide on bootstrap 3.3.4 carousel and stop when next or previous slide here is my example js code

```
$('#myCarousel').bind('slid', function (e) {
$('#videoId').get(0).play()
});
```

here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/umergetsol/vq6pjagr/

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution for this i don't know it's efficient or not but it works well for me :)

```
 $("#video").on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
 $("#video .video").empty();
 $("#video .item.active").addClass('animated fadeIn');
 $("#video #vid-1.active .video").append('<video muted loop autoplay class="media-player" src="videos/4696286.mp4" id="fast"><source src="videos/4696286.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source></video>');
 $("#video #vid-2.active .video").append('<video muted loop autoplay class="media-player" src="videos/7883158.mp4" id="fast"><source src="videos/7883158.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source></video>');
 $("#video #vid-3.active .video").append('<video muted loop autoplay class="media-player" src="videos/8075803.mp4" id="fast"><source src="videos/8075803.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source></video>');
 $("#video #vid-4.active .video").append('<video muted loop autoplay class="media-player" src="videos/1138051.mp4" id="fast"><source src="videos/1138051.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source></video>');
 $("#video #vid-5.active .video").append('<video muted loop autoplay class="media-player" src="videos/1675216.mp4" id="fast"><source src="videos/1675216.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source></video>');
});
```